# No space left on device MANJARO

Tags: linux, tmp, manjaro

I am using Manjaro Linux and i want to install Android Studio Beta from "Manjaro Package Manager".

When I press the "install" button, it downloads 845 megabytes of data. And then I get a "no space left on device" error. But there is 45 gigabytes.

I do not have a swap partition

In `etc/yaourtrc` :
    `#TMPDIR="/tmp"`

but i did not use the `yaourt` command

Answer (score 0):

Your tmp dir is limited. When you do df -h what is it? Also is it going to be installed in /opt? Take a look at all those things and then go from there.

Comment: `Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

dev             3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev

run             3.8G  1.6M  3.8G   1% /run
/dev/sda6        65G   19G   44G  30% /
tmpfs           3.8G   56M  3.8G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           3.8G   44M  3.8G   2% /tmp
/dev/sda2        96M   29M   68M  30% /boot/efi
tmpfs           773M   44K  773M   1% /run/user/1000`